# Broken Hibernate Save Method

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

I have the following method in my Java application's DAO layer:

```
public void save(Employee emp) {
     System.out.println("emp type: " + emp.getClass().getName);
     getHibernateTemplate().save(emp);
     System.out.println("object saved!");
     System.out.flush();
}
```

The employee class does not extend from any other classes and has the following hbm file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>    
 <class name="org.myCompany.Employee" table="employee">
 <!-- fields omitted to save space -->
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Yet the insert fails with a java.lang.ClassCastException. At first, I thought something was wrong with my mapping (like an Integer mapping to a boolean) but then I turned on hibernate's show_sql debugging and found the following in my log file:

> emp type: org.myCompany.Employee
>   Hibernate: insert into customer
>   (.......) values (......)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException

Why did it pick an entirely random table to insert into? I'm sure that I must have some config file mis-configured, but I don't know which one. I checked the following:

- applicationContext-hibernate.xml -> both the Customer and Employee objects are mapped to their correct hbm files
- neither Customer or Employee have an inheritance relationship (there isn't even a common parent class like Person or User)

What else could I try?

Comment: Show the full stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 0):

In the calling class, I have the following two calls:

```
UserDAO.saveCustomer(customer);
UserDAO.saveEmployee(employee);
```

I thought that the customer object was saving correctly. I even put a debugging statement between the two calls and the debug method printed. However, commenting out the UserDAO.saveCustomer line fixed the problem. This made me examine the customer object more closely and I found that it was corrupt (wrong class). Hibernate must have been caching the insert statement until the Transaction was complete.

So this issue is now resolved.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting an answer, generally